# Refreshing listview duplicates content

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have a listview which populated with arraylist. However, anytime I use the pull to refresh, the data in the listview gets duplication even though I clear the arraylist before populating. This is my arraylist

```
List<TimeItems> myList = new ArrayList<TimeItems>();
```

and this is how I am populating the adapter

```
for (int in = 0; in <= video.size() - 1; in ++) {
                    String a = vDancers.get(in);
                    String b = video.get(in);
                    String c = vName.get(in);

                    TimeLineItems item = new TimeLineItems(a,b,c);
                    myList.add(item);
                }

                Collections.sort(myList);
                you = new MyVideoAdapter(getActivity(), myList,nLikes,nComments,nRepost);
                //you.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listView.setAdapter(you);
```

and this is how I am clearing myList on pull-to-refresh

```
 listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    you = null;
                    nComments.clear();
                    nRepost.clear();
                    nRepost.clear();
                    myList.clear();

                    parseFetch();
                    listView.onRefreshComplete();
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
```

where you is my BaseAdapter and parseFetch() is my method to load network data. How do I completely clear myList before refresh so I don't have duplicated in my listview? Thanks for your help

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged() for any data change associated with adapter and use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetInvalidated() for invalidating current data in adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I wasn't also clearing the other arrays I was using to populate myList. After logging the various stages, I realised these arrays were duplicated so I just needed to clear them as well. This is the final work.Thanks @Lavkush2oct and @Vesko for the help.

```
listView.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                you = null;
                nComments.clear();
                nRepost.clear();
                nRepost.clear();
                myList.clear();
                vDancers.clear();
                video.clear();
                vName.clear();
                you.notifyDataSetChanged();
                parseFetch();
                listView.onRefreshComplete();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the code snippets I see, I'm left with the impression you're using an `ArrayAdapter`. If that's really.the case why do you manipulate `myList` after your adapter `you` is initialised?

All you can do is call

```
you.clear()
// add your data with you.add(item)
```

Comment: I am using BaseAdaper and I can't even access the clear function on the adapter. The dot notation doesn't show the clear method.

Answer (score 1):

Call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on your list adapter.
Remove this line `you = null;`

`myList.clear();
you.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: Can you post your full code. You might be missing something which duplicates the arraylist.

Comment: is there any similiar solution for recycler views... I am using card views to be populated inside recycler view.

Comment: Yes. You can use notifyDataSetChanged with recycle view adapter as well. However, you can have the better-controlled update for a particular item or item range with notifyItemChanged(--) apis.
Please refer documentation for more info.